# React-table. How to server-side filter. Query string

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose, react-table

I am using react-table and server-side filtering. 
The problem is that when filtering filters are not apply together. If I filter by name and the by category for example, the name filter resets.

the url looks like this:

```
http://localhost:3001/api/v1/products?pages=0&pageSize=20&filtered[]=%7B%22id%22:%22name%22,%22value%22:%22j%22%7D&filtered[]=%7B%22id%22:%22comment%22,%22value%22:%22f%22%7D".
```

I don't know if it is normal that `filter[]=` is called each time I try to filter by different column or if there is a problem in server-side.

This is the controller:

```
exports.index = function (req, res) {
 let filtered = {}
 let filters = {}

  if (req.query.filtered) {
req.query.filtered.map(result => {
  filtered = JSON.parse(result)
})

let id = filtered.id
let value = filtered.value
if (filtered['id'] === 'name' || filtered['id'] === 'comment') {
  filters[id] = { '$regex': value, '$options': 'i' }
} else {
  filters[id] = value
}
  }

  Product.listWithCategory(filters).then(response => {
res.json({ result: response })
   })
}
```

React onFetchData:

```
onFetchData = (state, instance) => {
const jwt = getJwt()
if (!jwt) {
  this.props.history.push('/login')
}
console.log(state.filtered)
let config = {
  headers: { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${jwt}` },
  params: {
    pages: state.page,
    pageSize: state.pageSize,
    sorted: state.sorted,
    filtered: state.filtered
  }
}

this.setState({ loading: true })

axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api/v1/products', config)
  .then(response => {
    this.setState({
      data: response.data.result,
      pages: response.data.pages,
      loading: false
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: does `onFetchData` even get called?

Comment: Yes It does, and it is filtering. The thing is that when I try to apply two or more filters (for example name, description and category) they do not apply together. I want to know if url is ok, and i am doing something wrong on server side, of if I am passing parameters correctly and url is ok

Comment: Its really hard to tell what's wrong without seeing the entire app, it could be several things. Can you strip down your example and recreate your issue with codesandbox.io?